# Access Query Doubling and Tripling Sums

Tags: sql, ms-access, office365

I have a query that joins a table (`Shelf`) and two other queries (`[Shelf Persons]`,`[Shelf Meals]`):

**`TABLE Shelf`:**

| Date | Family | Male | Female | Elderly | Children |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/5/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 7/5/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

**`VIEW [Shelf Persons]`:**

| Date | Gender | CountOfGender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/5/2023 | F | 2 |
| 7/5/2023 | M | 2 |
| 7/6/2023 | F | 3 |
| 7/6/2023 | M | 1 |

SQL:

```
SELECT
    Q.[Date],
    Q.Gender,
    Sum(Q.N) AS CountOfGender

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Date],
            "F" AS Gender,
            Female AS N
        FROM
            Shelf
        WHERE
            Female > 0

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [Date],
            "M" AS Gender,
            Male AS N
        FROM
            Shelf
        WHERE
            Male > 0
    ) AS Q

GROUP BY
    Q.[Date],
    Q.Gender

HAVING
    (
        ( (Q.[Date]) BETWEEN [Forms]![Report Parameters]![Start Date] And [Forms]![Report Parameters]![End Date] )
    );
```

**`VIEW [Shelf Meals]`:**

| Date | SumOfCountOfGender | Meals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/5/2023 | 4 | 36 |
| 7/6/2023 | 4 | 36 |

SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Shelf Persons].Date,
    SUM( [Shelf Persons].CountOfGender ) AS SumOfCountOfGender, 
    SUM( [CountOfGender] * 9           ) AS Meals

FROM
    [Shelf Persons]

GROUP BY
    [Shelf Persons].Date;
```

The query that joins them all:

```
SELECT
    Shelf.Date, 
    COUNT( Shelf.Date                  ) AS CountOfDate, 
    SUM( Shelf.Family                  ) AS SumOfFamily, 
    SUM( [Shelf Persons].CountOfGender ) AS SumOfCountOfGender, 
    SUM( [Shelf Meals].Meals           ) AS SumOfMeals, 
    SUM( Shelf.Elderly                 ) AS SumOfElderly, 
    SUM( Shelf.Children                ) AS SumOfChildren

FROM
    (
        Shelf 
        LEFT JOIN [Shelf Persons] ON Shelf.Date = [Shelf Persons].Date
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN [Shelf Meals] ON Shelf.Date = [Shelf Meals].Date

GROUP BY
    Shelf.Date

HAVING
    (
        ( ( Shelf.Date ) BETWEEN [Forms]![Report Parameters]![Start Date] AND [Forms]![Report Parameters]![End Date] )
    );
```

When I run it, I get these results:

| Date | CountOfDate | SumOfFamily | SumOfCountOfGender | SumOfMeals | SumOfElderly | SumOfChildren |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/5/2023 | 6 | 2 | 12 | 216 | 8 | 0 |
| 7/6/2023 | 8 | 0 | 16 | 288 | 6 | 0 |
| 7/7/2023 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 36 | 1 | 0 |
| 7/11/2023 | 6 | 0 | 9 | 162 | 6 | 0 |

What I should be getting for results is this:

| Date | CountOfDate | SumOfFamily | SumOfCountOfGender | SumOfMeals | SumOfElderly | SumOfChildren |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/5/2023 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 36 | 4 | 0 |
| 7/6/2023 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 36 | 3 | 0 |
| 7/7/2023 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 18 | 1 | 0 |
| 7/11/2023 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 27 | 3 | 0 |

I have scoured the Internet looking for the solution to this problem. What I have done is managed to pinpoint the problem: I'm aggregating before the JOIN. However, when I tried to modify the SQL to fix the problem, I'd either get a syntax error, or when I got the syntax "right", I'd end up with null values.

Please bear in mind that most of my Access is self-taught, and I've only recently started to dip my toes (fingers?) into SQL. If you use too much jargon, I might not comprehend you.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Research "sql one-to-many" and you'll find many examples and solutions.

Comment: Please show us your `Shelf Meals` and `Shelf Persons` tables - both their structure and sample data (you can use your actual data if you prefer, but you must obfuscate any PII).

Comment: build the sums before you join them

Comment: You say that the `[Shelf Persons]` and `[Shelf Meals]` objects are _queries_ (i.e. SQL `VIEW` objects) - can you share their definition? BTW, when using `JOIN` it usually only makes-sense to `JOIN ON` some _key_ (primary-key, unique-key, or foreign-key) attribute/column - but you are doing `JOIN ON Date`, but those `Date` values are not distinctive or apparently meaningful - so I can't tell what you're trying to do here....

Comment: Please explain what the `CountOfGender` and `SumCountOfGender` columns are meant to represent. Because your `VIEW` is named `Shelf Persons` my expectation is that each row represents a single person/human, but the `CountOfGender` column looks like an aggregate implying that each row in `Shelf Persons` corresponds to multiple underlying rows, but having only `Date` and `Gender` makes it impossible to uniquely identify each row...

Comment: @Dai. What do you mean by "definition"? The Primary Key is already taken. The Dates are useful because I need to give monthly reports on these tallies. So I use the dates for my parameters.

Comment: By "definition" I mean getting the raw SQL `SELECT...` _inside_ `Shelf Persons` and `Shelf Meals`: in MSAccess, find those Queries in the Object List, right-click and choose "Design View", then change the View mode from "Datasheet view" or "Design view" to "SQL View", then copy-and-paste that into your question-post.

Comment: @Dai The CountOfGender is so I have a count of each Gender that visited our shelf. I need that data for another report (which is working fine). The SumOfCountOfGender is so that I can get a total count of how many individuals visited the shelf.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the primary-key is already taken" - I'm not seeing any columns that _look like_ PKs in your query so-far. Your `Date` column cannot be your PK because you've shown that (at least) two rows in `Shelf` have the exact same `Date` values.

Comment: @Dai. I was mistaken. I thought you could only have 1 primary key per db. That being said, there isn't anything in the table that I could make the primary key because that requires a distinct value for each record, and this is very literally a tally.

Comment: What do the tallys represent?

Comment: @Dai The tallies represent the people that come in and take food from our shelf. Unless I know them personally or have a file on them, it's anonymous, but I still need monthly numbers on how many people visit the shelf for stats.

Comment: So every time someone makes use of your shelf/pantry it gets a new row in the `Shelf` table? If you add a time-of-day or visit-number column then you could use that, along with `Date`, as a composite primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our conversation in the comments section, your `Shelf` table contains *pre-aggregated* data of each visit-to-the-shelf, while the `Shelf Persons` and `Shelf Meals` VIEWs ("Queries" in MSAccess terminology) return data derived from the `Shelf` table.

The reason you're seeing those unexpected doubling or tripling of values is because your main query ("...that joins them all") performs the `JOIN` on non-distinct columns (i.e. non-key attributes) **before** it does the `GROUP BY Shelf.Date` step.

Specifically, the problem originates in `VIEW [Shelf Persons]`: the data returned from `[Shelf Persons]` has a `GROUP BY` step, but it does `GROUP BY Date, Gender` rather than just `GROUP BY Date`, so it will return multiple rows (one row for each distinct `Gender` value) for each `Date` value:

So if your `Shelf` contains these 2 rows...

(I've added a ficitious "`RowId`" column so you can identify each source row in `Shelf` in the tables below):

| RowId | Date | Family | Male | Female | Elderly | Children |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7/5/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 102 | 7/5/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

...and if `Shelf Persons` contains these 2 rows...

| Date | Gender | CountOfGender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/5/2023 | F | 16 |
| 7/5/2023 | M | 8 |

...then the result  of `Shelf LEFT JOIN [Shelf Persons] ON Shelf.Date = [Shelf Persons].Date` (*without* performing the `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, or `SUM` aggregate steps)  will be these **4 rows** not 2: this is because in relational-algebra (and SQL) a `JOIN` is (conceptually) *first*: the Cartesian Product of two tables *then* the product is filtered by the `JOIN` criteria.

| Shelf.RowId | Shelf.Date | Shelf.Family | Shelf.Male | Shelf.Female | Shelf.Elderly | Shelf.Children | Persons.Gender | Persons.CountOfGender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7/5/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | F | 16 |
| 101 | 7/5/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | M | 8 |
| 102 | 7/5/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | F | 16 |
| 102 | 7/5/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | M | 8 |

...so if you observe the `Shelf.RowId` values you'll see how the `JOIN` caused the rows in `Shelf` to be repeated for each `Date` value in `[Shelf Persons].Date`.

---

A solution would be to modify your query to add an additional `GROUP BY [Date]` step to **only** the `[Shelf Persons]` view - but as `[Shelf Persons]` is derived from `Shelf` already, I don't really see a point in doing that when we can implement the same logic in a single query anyway.

Like so:

```
SELECT
    s2.[Date],
    COUNT( * )      AS Count_Shelf_rows_for_this_date,
    SUM( s2.Family   ) AS Sum_Family,
    SUM( s2.Elderly  ) AS Sum_Elderly,
    SUM( s2.Children ) AS Sum_Children,
    SUM( s2.Adults   ) AS Sum_Adults,
    SUM( s2.Meals    ) AS Sum_Meals

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s.Date,
            s.Family,
            s.Elderly,
            s.Children,
            s.Male + s.Female AS Adults,
            ( s.Male + s.Female ) * 9 AS Meals
        FROM
            Shelf AS s
        WHERE
            ( s.[Date] BETWEEN [Forms]![Report Parameters]![Start Date] AND [Forms]![Report Parameters]![End Date] )
    ) AS s2

GROUP BY
    s2.[Date]

ORDER BY
    s2.[Date];
```

- This query's `Count_Shelf_rows_for_this_date` column is equivalent to your `CountOfDate` column.
- And `Sum_Adults` corresponds to your `SumOfCountOfGender` column.
- And `Sum_Meals` corresponds to `SumOfMeals`.
- I assume your `Shelf` columns are all `NOT NULL` - but if they are `NULL`-able then the `s.Male + s.Female` expression will fail (as `NULL` values cannot be used as arithmetic operands), but the fix is to change the `Adults` and `Meals` expressions in the inner `s2` query like so:

```
SELECT
    s.Date,
    s.Family,
    s.Elderly,
    s.Children,
    IIF( s.Male IS NULL, 0, s.Male ) + IIF( s.Female IS NULL, 0, s.Female ) AS Adults,
    ( IIF( s.Male IS NULL, 0, s.Male ) + IIF( s.Female IS NULL, 0, s.Female ) ) * 9 AS Meals
FROM
    Shelf AS s
```

Comment: I tried copy-pasting these, and all I got were syntax errors.

Comment: What version of MS Access are you using? And where are you pasting it into?

Comment: @ Dai, I'm pasting into the SQL view. I tried to find the version. All I can find is that it's part of Office 365 and this: (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164)

Comment: Would you be comfortable with sending me a copy of your Access database so I can have a look?

Comment: It has confidential client information in it. If I'm going to send it to you, I'll have to make a dummy version which would take me a minute.

Comment: Can you do that? Also, I assume you can upload it to Google Drive or OneDrive or whathaveyou and share a link here?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsysn28nJpzoqJvajtzOgovv0loX1Ks2/view?usp=sharing I also "trimmed the fat" on it, as in I took out the stuff you're prolly not gonna need. The query in question is USDA: Shelf Counts.

Comment: @C-Note Thanks - fortunately it's just a couple of things to change: change `COUNT( s2.* )` to `COUNT(*)` and remove the `)` after `s.[Date]`. I've updated my answer.